# Python csv package - issue with DictReader module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, utf-8, python-unicode

I'm having a curious issue with the csv package in Python 3.7.

I'm importing a csv file and able to access all the file as expected, with one exception - the header row, as stored in the "fieldnames" object, appears have the first column header (first item in fieldnames) malformed.

This first field always has the format: `'xxx"header"'`

where:

1. `xxx` are garbage characters that always seem to be the same
2. `header` is the correct header text

See the following screenshot of my `table <csv.DictReader>` object from my debug window:
[image]

My code to open the file, follows. I added the `headers[0] = table.fieldnames[0].split('"')[1] in order to extract the correct header and place it back into` fieldnames`.

```py
import csv

  with self.inputfile.open() as self.inputfid:
    table = csv.DictReader(self.inputfid, delimiter=',')
    headers = table.fieldnames
    headers[0] = table.fieldnames[0].split('"')[1]
```

(**Note:** `self.inputfile` is a `pathlib.Path` object)

I didn't notice this for a long time because I wasn't using the first column (with the # header) - I've been happily parsing with the rest of the columns for a while on multiple files.

If I look directly at the csv, there doesn't appear to be any issue:

[image: ```csv]

---

#### Questions:

Does anyone know what the issue is?  Is there anything I can try to correct the import issue?

If there isn't a fix, is there a better way to parse the garbage?  I realize this could clear up in the future, but I think the split will still work even with just bare double quotes (the header should still be the 2nd item in the split, right?). Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your csv file is encoded as *utf-8-sig* - a version of utf-8 used by some Windows applications, but it's being decoded as *cp1252* - another encoding in common use on Windows.

```
>>> print('"#"'.encode('utf-8-sig').decode('cp1252'))
ï»¿"#"
```

The "garbage" characters preceding the header are the byte-order-mark that utf-8-sig uses to tell Windows applications that a file is [encoded](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) as utf-8 rather than one of the historically more common 8-bit encodings.

To avoid the "garbage", specify utf-8-sig as the encoding when opening your file.

The code in the question could be modified to work like this:

```
import csv

encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
with self.inputfile.open(encoding=encoding, newline='') as self.inputfid:
    table = csv.DictReader(self.inputfid, delimiter=',')
    headers = table.fieldnames
    ...
```

If - as seems likely - the encoding of input files may vary, the value of `encoding` (or a best guess) must be determined by using a tool like [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/), as used in the comments.

Comment: Great - that makes sense.  Have the info on how to apply the `utf-i-sig` encoding when opening a file with the csv package?

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of object is `self.inputfile`?

Comment: `self.inputfile` is a `pathlib.Path` object. P.S. I used the `chardet` package and confirmed the encoding was `utf-8-sig`.